# Decorating all functions in a file if variable is set to true in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I have the code

```
chop_flag = True

def decorator(func):
    def chop_num(num):
        num = str(num)
        num = num[:15]
        return float(num)
    return chop_num

def decorator2():
    return decorator if chop_flag else break
```

And then before each function in my program I add `@decorator2`. This is producing a type error ("decorator2() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given") and I'm also pretty sure this is not a great way to do what I'm trying to do.

To summarize: I'm trying to take the output of each function in my program and run it through the `chop_num()` function if `chop_flag = True`; if `chop_flag = False`, I want it to just ignore the decorator. I thought I'd do this by applying a decorator to each function. Any help would be appreciated.

---

#### Updated code:

```
chop_flag = True

def decorator(func):
    if chop_flag == True:
        def chop_num(num, *args, **kwargs):
            num = func(*args, **kwargs)
            num = str(num)
            num = num[:15]
            return float(num)
        return chop_num
    else:
        return
```

It now runs properly, but when I import my file into the interpreter (for example) and call the add function, it says "add() missing 1 required positional argument" even though I have put in two arguments.

Comment: Couldn't you define a normal decorator to apply to each function, and within it test `chop_flag` to decide whether the decorator does anything?

Comment: @ScottHunter that would...make more sense, yes. I'll try that, thank you.

Comment: @ScottHunter so it works in the sense that nothing is immediately broken, but I have a new problem - the chop_num function is running on the inputs to the function I apply the decorator to, instead of the output.

Comment: You never actually call `func` in `chop_num`.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh when i try to do so it says that the various functions it is used on are missing "required positional arguments". I saw elsewhere that *args and **kwargs are used and it simply returns a name error: "args is not defined".

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I have updated the question with some new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your final decorator should look more like this

```
def chop_num(num):
    num = str(num)
    num = num[:15]
    return float(num)

chop_flag = True

def decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        val = func(*args, **kwargs)
        if chop_flag:
            return chop_num(val)
        else:
            return val
    return wrapper

@decorator
def nineteen_digits():
    return 1_000_000_000_000_000_000

print(nineteen_digits())
# 100000000000000.0
chop_flag = False
print(nineteen_digits())
# 1000000000000000000
```

Comment: Thank you, this works really well! I will accept this answer. I clearly have a lot more to figure out about decorators. =)